# Kendo Grid Custom Button To Call Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do you tie a custom button to a JavaScript function? I see the button on each row in the grid, but clicking on the buttons refreshes the page with a "/0" appended to the current URL. It does not call the JavaScript function "RedirectCreateReport". Here is my Kendo grid:

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                  .Name("MyGrid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                               {
                                   columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
                                   columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title("Description");
                                   columns.Command(command =>
                                       {
                                           command.Custom("CreateReport").Text("Submit Report").Click("RedirectCreateReport");
                                       }).Title("Actions");
                               })
                  ...
                  .ColumnMenu()
                  .Groupable())

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".RedirectCreateReport").click(function () {
                alert("a");
                var item = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
                window.location.href = "/Report/Create?P=" + item;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Your sample code is confusing because you don't have a JavaScript function named `RedirectCreateReport`, and you do a jQuery selector against elements with the class `.RedirectCreateReport` but nothing in the code you show is assigning that class to anything.

Comment: I have changed the jQuery to a standard JavaScript function, but it still behaves the same way:
        function RedirectCreateReport() {
            alert("a");
            var item = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
            window.location.href = "/Report/Create?P=" + item;
        }

Comment: It doesn't matter if the solution uses JavaScript or jQuery. I just need to be able to click on a button in a Kendo Grid row, and have it redirect to another page, passing the Item Id from the referring page to the target page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question: Ditch the custom button. Use an ActionLink, styled as a button instead:

```
 columns.Template(
   p => @Html.ActionLink(
     "New Report", 
     "Create", 
     "Report", 
     new { ID = p.Id.ToString() }, 
     htmlAttributes: 
     new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-NewReport" }
     ).ToHtmlString()
   );
```

This code replaces the lines columns.Command(command => ...).Title("Actions");
No JavaScript is necessary.